# Структура C# кода в Unity проектах / Паттерны

Tags: c#, unity3d, шаблоны-проектирования

Доброго времени суток!

Очень часто появляется такой вопрос: если метод не относится логически ну никак к данному классу, а класс с одним методом создавать, тоже, не хочется, то как быть в таких ситуациях? Логика во многих классах присутствует лишняя, но необходимая. Например, метод, который, перемешивает значения массива в скрипте, который, генерирует блоки.

Хочется, чтобы код был с максимально простой логикой. Можете подсказать, как лучше всего структурировать код в Unity проектах?

P.S. *класс — наследующий класс MonoBehaviour. (компонент, скрипт)

Comment: не знаю, как насчет Unity, но если вам нужно куда то положить служебный метод, который не относится к вашей логике и делает какую то маленькую операцию (например, перемешать значения в массиве) - то вы можете сделать с помощью метода расширения

Comment: Я для таких вещей создаю один класс Utils и туда все эти методы пихаю.